# JavaFX WebView: how can I load webjars?

Tags: java, jquery, javafx, webview, webjars

I installed the jquery webjar with gradles:

```
implementation group: 'org.webjars', name: 'jquery', version: '3.3.1'
```

How do I use the resulting webjar from JavaFX WebView? The location of the file is

`META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`

I then load the content of the WebView with `webEngine.loadContent(content)`. Said content includes

```html
<script src="webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However, jquery isn't loaded for some reason.

Alternatively, I tried

```html
<script src="META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and

```html
<script src="/META-INF/resources/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But jquery still doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `/META-INF/resources` from the src uri.  Assuming that is the path in your app jar file or classpath.

Comment: @jewelsea that's not it, I tried that path and it still doesn't work

Comment: @guillaume-f did you find the answer?